# Sharepoint 2013 Workflow - time jobs

Tags: 2013, workflow

If there is a function in Sharepoint 2013 workflow, that can ask a database in the specyfic time. Can I put a workflow, that can ask a database for example at two o clock everyday ? Like Time Job in MS SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this required by workflow process or are you trying to use workflow just to contact DB and update specific list item in the list?

If yes - it might be work looking into writing a custom Timer Job.

If you have to do this in workflow - I guess you could build a custom activity and make it do all the required calls from there - someone who is workflow wizard would have to confirm as I never really been forced to do so in workflow.

But as with everything - depends on what you are trying to achieve :)

Comment: And it is On Sharepoint 2010 and 2013 too or only in Sharepoint 2013 ?

Comment: Timer Jobs are available in both 2010 and 2013. As to custom workflow activities - you can create them in 2010 as well (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13604.sharepoint-2010-create-a-workflow-activity-using-visual-studio-2010.aspx) *that's assuming that your workflow is created in SharePoint Designer

Answer (score 1):

You may follow this link which has clear explanation of how create to create a timer job.
It may help you.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/403323/SharePoint-Create-Custom-Timer-Jobs

Comment: Please add more details to this answer, it should not be so dependent on a link